# Open Instagram from Android Browser

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, hook, instagram

Intent, hooks, API, integration, dozen of cryptic javascripts, xml schemas, URL interpreters, helpers, frameworks...

It's 3 days that i'm reading blogs, SDK, tutorials to achive a very simple goal: open Instagram by clicking an URL in the Android browser. I find it a bit incredible that i needed 5 minutes to make it on iOS. I don't even know what code i should share since i don't even succeded in having an error... at least it would be something!

To make it short i have an Android phone. I open the browser to visit my website. Now i want to add a link to open Instagram camera. On iOS i simply reference to:

```
<a href="instagram://app">Open Instagram</a>
<a href="instagram://camera">Take a picture</a>
```

Is it really that hard to code the same thing on Android? I'm not looking to make it inside another App. It's just a normal website.

Comment: Have been trying to do the same with Waze, I think (yet not sure) that adding http:// before instagram://app may solve your problem (probably that's what i've done in order to open Waze from Android browser)

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Sadly it didn't work. I just get an error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of researches and tests - yeah, even more :S - i can finally state that it's not possible unless you want to force your visitors to manually download additional contents. I don't like it. It isn't an elegant and easy solution.

Please notice that i'm only talking for **websites**. You you are developing an App you can achive this quite easily with intents.